# Flask: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Tags: python, image, opencv, flask, upload

I am uploading an `img` through **html** and process it in open cv and display the image. I have `arg parsers` in `upload_file.py`. So I am running directly the application as python3 upload_file.py --listofargs

> **template.html**

```
<html>
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="imageInput" name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
           <li class="list-group-item">
               <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Colorize</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
</form>
<img src = {{image}}>
</html>
```

> **upload_file.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import cv2
from flask import jsonify
import argparse
import numpy as np


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
   return render_template('template.html')
@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST','GET'])
def handle_data():
   img = request.form['file']
   image = np.array(img)
   cv2.imshow("Original", image)
   return render_template(template.html, image = image)
```

> **How it is working ?**

1. I am running the flask application directly as `python3 upload_file.py --listofargs` without using `flask run` command.
2. When I click on colorize I get the above error **`Internal server error`**

How do I fix the error so that I could read the uploaded `img` properly through `html` and display back the `opencv img` through flask?

Comment: Provide complete error message, **including** the traceback. | That said, not sure what you expect to achieve by calling `cv2.imshow` on the server side (that function requires GUI on the machine where it executes), let alone without `cv2.waitKey` following it. I would also assume that `request.form['file']` doesn't contain raw pixel data, but rather an encoded image (in which case you need to `cv2.imdecode` it first).

Comment: Yep you cannot send a numpy array through Flask. Use `cv2.imdecode()` on it first then you can display it

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 you can do it like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from io import BytesIO # not necessary?

def handle_data():
   img = request.form['file']

   image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(BytesIO(img).read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

   cv2.imshow("Original", image) # Why do you need this?
   return render_template('template.html', image = image) # Don't forget the quotes?
```

That should get you far enough to handle the html rendering yourself [I am not an expert on that - but if someone else can assist I will incorporate it into this answer.]

Let me know if that works for you